# The server tag is not well formed. html runat="server" and data-target="#<% Eval("Abbreviation")%>"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have to generate checkboxes, which i have to check when a button is clicked.
When the checkbox is clicked it needs to use the "data-target" to uncollapse some code.

I need both the collapse and getting if its checked.

Problems:
the runat="server" and data-targer="#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>" gets my compiler saying "The server tag is not well formed".

When i try to get the "chk.checked" on serveside it says it doesn't know it since i can't have runat="server" if i have the data-target.

Here is the html code for the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ferryRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="div1" runat="server">
                    <input  id="chkFerry"  type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" runat="server" data-target="#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>"  />
                    <!--data-target="#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>" -->
                    <label id="label1" for="chk1"><%# Eval("SubcontractorName") %></label>
                    <div id="<%# Eval("Abbreviation") %>" class="collapse obligatorisk">
                        <dl>
                            <dt id="toFrom1"></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <p id="text1"><%# Eval("DialogueText") %></p>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the backend code for checking the checkboxes.

```
private List<string> CheckFerryCheckbox()
{
    List<string> ferryList = new List<string>();
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in ferryRepeater.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkFerry");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            Label ferry = (Label)item.FindControl("label1");
            ferryList.Add(ferry.Text);
        }
    }

    return ferryList;
}
```

Here is where i Binding with the repeater.

```
private void BindRepeaterData()
{
    string sqlString = @"SELECT sc.SubcontractorName, dt.DialogueText, sc.Abbreviation FROM dbo.Subcontractor sc LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DialogueText dt ON sc.DialogueId = dt.DialogueId WHERE sc.Active = 1 AND sc.Type = 'Færge' ORDER BY sc.SubcontractorName";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    ferryRepeater.DataSource = ds;
    ferryRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

I have tried to change Data-target to data-target='#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>' and have runat="server", but then it doesn't generate the Eval.

Sorry if this is not that well explained. It is my first post here, so please be gentle.

Comment: Try this: `<input  id="chkFerry"  type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" runat="server" data-target='<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>'  />` Note single quotes around data-target value

Comment: If i do this, then i get this error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>

When trying to check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
Note the use of `String.Format` method for data-target:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ferryRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="div1" runat="server">
                    <input  id="chkFerry"  type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" runat="server" data-target='<%# String.Format("#{0}", Eval("Abbreviation"))%>'  />

                    <label id="label1" for="chk1"><%# Eval("SubcontractorName") %></label>
                    <div id="<%# Eval("Abbreviation") %>" class="collapse obligatorisk">
                        <dl>
                            <dt id="toFrom1"></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <p id="text1"><%# Eval("DialogueText") %></p>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: This fixed the error on click. So one of the problem is solved, now i got the problem with checking if its checked or not. since you solved one of the problems how do i then proceed on stackoverflow? Do i accept your answer and write a new question or how is that handled?

Comment: You can mark this question as answered. You want to check whether checkbox is checked on client side or server side?

Comment: i want to check the checkbox on the server side.

Comment: Is it something you can help with? :)

Comment: In Page_Load method have you added the condition `if (!IsPostBack)` before calling the `BindRepeaterData` method? Also, does the following code works `HtmlInputCheckBox chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)item.FindControl("chkFerry"); if(chk.Checked)` ?

Comment: I just added the if (!IsPostBack). The code for the check of checkbox works, i slightly changed it since it now is a asp:checkbox and therefor not a HtmlInputCheckbox but instead is a CheckBox. I tested it, with a plain int that increase eachtime i get into the if (Checked) loop and it works as expected. But when i check whats in my ferrylist, its only empty strings. Like i am not getting the correct data from my Label.Text.

Comment: Try this: `HtmlGenericControl ferry = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("label1"); ferryList.Add(ferry.InnerText);`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use double quotes on the eval. As an example:

```
data-target="#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>"
```

Should be:

```
data-target='#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>'
```

As a whole:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ferryRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id='div1_<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>' runat="server">
                <input  id='chkFerry_<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>'  type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" runat="server" data-target='#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>'  />
                <!--data-target="#<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>" -->
                <label id='label1_<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>' for='chkFerry_<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>'><%# Eval("SubcontractorName") %></label>
                <div id='<%# Eval("Abbreviation") %>' class="collapse obligatorisk">
                    <dl>
                        <dt id='toFrom1_<%# Eval("Abbreviation") %>'></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <p id='text1_<%# Eval("Abbreviation") %>'><%# Eval("DialogueText") %></p>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: If i do this, then i get this error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>

When trying to check the checkbox.

Comment: Also your IDs need to be unique per control.  You can't repeat the same ID for each row.  Also, have you tried using an asp:Checkbox instead of HTML inputs and also Asp:Panel for Divs?

Comment: If inspect the website it generate the id's. I used the Asp:Panel and Asp:Checkbox. But it still give me the error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%# Eval("Abbreviation")%>

Comment: Please provide us with your datasource code for the repeater (i.e. your page load / other page function code and also the data you are sending to the repeater)

Comment: I added the code where i bind my repeater data. I just run the BindRepeaterData() function in my Page_Load.

Comment: Although, the accepted answer is not this but it was the correct answer as the exception clearly suggests it was formatting error for server tag and that was because the twice use of double quotes with a # before adding a C# snippet in the server tags attribute.